# Как получить id страницы (не записи) в Wordpress средствами PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет. Речь пойдет о CMS Wordpress. Задача - нужно получить id страницы (не записи), которая сейчас открыта пользователем в файле functions.php темы. Это нужно для того, чтобы некоторый код продолжал работу после настройки ЧПУ (постоянные ссылки, mod_rewrite). Версия Wordpress 4.2.1

Пробовал такие варианты, но они не работают:

```
// Since 3.1 - recommended!
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();


// "Dirty" pre 3.1
global $wp_query;

$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил так:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$postid = url_to_postid($url);
```

Answer (score 3):

`get_the_ID()` - внутри шаблона `page.php` возвращает ID. 
Попробуй использовать эту ф-цию в `functions.php`

Comment: Проверил. В `functions.php` тоже срабатывает.